# PostgreSQL to_tsvector generated column with table column for configuration name

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, immutability, postgresql-14

I want to use stored generated column to create a separate tsvector column to hold the output of to_tsvector. The config name for the ts_vector is stored in the separate column `language_field`. Similarly to sql for creating ts_vector index I thought that using column name for the ts_vector config can be possible. But I got an error `[42P17] ERROR: generation expression is not immutable`

Here is the code which I use:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD COLUMN textsearchable_index_col tsvector
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
    to_tsvector("table_name"."language_field"::regconfig, COALESCE("table_name"."name", ''))
) STORED;
```

Is it possible to use column name as a vector config in the stored generated column?

If I explicitly set config name during column generation (`to_tsvector('english', coalesce("table_name"."name", '')`) and then the text in the `"table_name"."name"` will change to some other language different from `english` does it mean that I need to recreate generated column with another config name? If so, maybe you can suggest possible workarounds / solutions.